# convert variable names to array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post

I have lite problem with converting PHP `$_POST` virables.

I send such information to the website:

```
$_POST['name.1']='xxx';
$_POST['height.1']='100';
$_POST['qty.1']='2';
$_POST['op.1.0']='color';
$_POST['op.1.1']='size';
$_POST['opv.1.0.0']='red';
$_POST['opv.1.0.1']='blue';
$_POST['opv.1.1.0']='xl';
$_POST['opv.1.1.1']='l';
$_POST['opv.1.1.2']='xxl';
$_POST['name.2']='yyy';
$_POST['height.2']='10';
$_POST['qty.2']='4';
$_POST['number.2']='4';
$_POST['op.2.0']='color';
$_POST['op.2.1']='weight';
$_POST['opv.2.0.0']='red';
$_POST['opv.2.0.1']='silver';
$_POST['opv.2.1.0']='90';
$_POST['opv.2.1.1']='60';
$_POST['opv.2.1.2']='42';
```

I need to convert this data into a format:

```
$product[1]['name']='xxx';
$product[1]['height']='100';
$product[1]['qty']='2';
$product[1]['op'][0]='color';
$product[1]['op'][1]=size;
$product[1]['opv'][0][0]='red';
$product[1]['opv'][0][1]='blue';
$product[1]['opv'][1][0]='xl';
$product[1]['opv'][1][1]='l';
$product[1]['opv'][1][2]='xxl';
$product[2]['name']='yyy';
$product[2]['height']='10';
$product[2]['qty']='2';
$product[2]['number']='2';
$product[2]['op'][0]='color';
$product[2]['op'][1]='weight';
$product[2]['opv'][0][0]='red';
$product[2]['opv'][0][1]='silver';
$product[2]['opv'][1][0]='90';
$product[2]['opv'][1][1]='60';
$product[2]['opv'][1][2]='42';


first .1 is product nr.
second .1 is option nr.
third .1 is option value.
```

Comment: I think you need a  combination of `foreach()` `array_keys()` and `explode()` functions.

Comment: 1. What pattern is behind this? 2. It's called: `variable` not `virable`

Comment: this can all be done by naming the HTML form inputs 'correctly'

Comment: You may not even need `array_keys()` actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $key_array = explode('.', $key);
    $name = array_shift($key_array);
    $subscript = array_shift($key_array);
    $target =& $product[$subscript][$name];
    // If there are remaining elements, they're subscripts into nested array levels
    foreach ($key_array as $next_subscript) {
        $target =& $target[$next_subscript];
    }
    $target = $value;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix the form, the laziest approach would be transforming the array via:

- `$post =`[`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query)`($_POST)`
- And a couple of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) calls:

  1. `("/\b(\w+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)=/", "prod[$2][$1][$3][$4]=", $post)`
  2. `("/\b(\w+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)=/", "prod[$2][$1][$3]=", $post)`
  3. `("/\b(\w+)\.(\d+)=/", "prod[$2][$1]=", $post)`
- Then converting it back to an array per [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str).

(Which really only works reliably because equal signs are escaped to `%3B` for values.)

You can do a manual loop of course to "just" restructure the keys, but that's a wee bit more code.